# What is the best way to have a button autofill a cell with the next available number from a column on another sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BAWAuHgwdyiXhcQ22XRL0Ilwz4MLBlR-qwIXCmYfsi4/edit?usp=sharing) containing two sheets; one is named Form, where data is entered, and another is named Data, where the entered data is received. What I am looking for is the best method of having an Autofill button on the Form sheet populate Cell B2 with the last number from Column A on the Data sheet, plus 1.

Currently I have this working via a formula: `=INDEX(Data!A2:A,COUNTA(Data!A2:A))+1` which is linked to cell F1 on the Data sheet and gets copied to Cell B2 on the Form sheet via a button linked to this code:

```
function AutoFill() {
   var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data');            
   var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form');            
   sheet1.getRange('F1').copyTo(sheet2.getRange('B2'),{contentsOnly:true})
}
```

..but this is hardly ideal. I'm guessing what would be best would be to convert the formula directly into a script, but I'm not sure how to convert its functionality. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to put the value to the cell "B2" of the sheet "Form".

  - The value, which added 1 to the last row of the column "A" of sheet "Data", is used as the value.
- You want to run the script by clicking a button of "AutoFill" on the Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that to use the formula can make the situation be simple. But if you want to change the value only when the button is clicked, to use a script might be suitable for achieving it. I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your script was modified. Please modify the function of `AutoFill` as follows.

```
function AutoFill() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form');
  var valueOfData = sheet1.getRange(sheet1.getLastRow(), 1).getValue(); // Added
  sheet2.getRange('B2').setValue(valueOfData + 1); // Added
}
```

- The value, which is the last row of the column "A" of sheet "Data", is retrieved. And it is put to the cell "B2" of the shee "Form" by adding 1 to the retrieved value.

#### References:

- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, very informative and very helpful, thank you so much!

Comment: @J. Kubassek Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.